# Error sending email using PHP MAILER

Tags: php

I have a database that has a table called mailing_list which has three columns first_name, last_name and email. This table has two people 
The first one first name is: x1 last name is: y1 and email is: x1@yahoo.com
The second one first name is: x2 last name is: y2 and email is: x2@yahoo.com
I am trying to use PHP Mailer and the code is below, what is happening is that x1 is getting the same email twice one with "Dear x1 y1" and the second time with "Dear x2 y2". The second name x2 is getting it one time which is fine. I don't want the same email to go to the person more than one time, and I know that there is something wrong with loop.  Any help please??
The sendemail.php page

```
 <?php
    require("config.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        require("class.phpmailer.php"); 
        $mail = new PHPMailer();        

        $query = "SELECT * FROM mailing_list";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)    
        or die('Error querying the database!');


            $mail->IsSMTP(); 
            $mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";       
            $mail->Username="myEmailAdd"; 
            $mail->Password="myPassWord"; //SMTP_PASS;
            $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
            $mail->From ="myEmailAdd";  
            $mail->FromName ="CSCA";    

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $to = $row['email'];

            $mail->AddAddress($to); 


            $mail->Subject= $_POST['subject'];

            $mail->Body = "Dear $first_name $last_name,\n" . $_POST['body'];
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;

            if(!$mail->Send()) 
            {
                echo 'Message was not sent.';
                echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo 'Message has been sent.';
                echo 'Email sent to ' . $to . '<br/>';
            }           

        }

        mysqli_close($connect); 
    }   
    ?>
```

And here is the email form

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="sendemail.php">
            <label for="subject">Subject of email:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="60"/><br/>
            <label for="body">Body of mail:</label><br/>
            <textarea id="body" name="body" rows="8" cols="60"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>             
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Of course that happens, because you are using `AddAddress` method in your loop. Use a method instead, that just sets a singular `To:` address, instead of adding multiple recipients.

Comment: I can’t spot an explicit method to add a single `To:` address (that would also clear previous ones while doing so) in the docs at a short glance – but there is a `clearAddresses` method, so call that before `AddAddress` in your loop, then it should work fine.

Comment: If you would bother to read the manual of what the class methods do you would not need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddAddress` method just adds another receiver’s email address to the ones that are already there, so it is only logical that you end up with the first recipient receiving the email a second time, when you use `AddAddress` in a loop.

Simply call `clearAddresses` method in your loop before you add an address with `AddAddress` – that will clear the current list of receiving email addresses, and give you a “fresh start”, so that the next address added will be the only receiving email address for the current send mail.